# wordpress hack with lots of post

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I'm having trouble with a wordpress site.

I've found that in the themes/theme-name folder two files where placed:
imagestyle.php and QAR_rss-collect.php

These where placed on a clean wordpress installation.
I looked in de database for any code injecten, but found nothing.

The logs show a lot post requests like:

```
178.126.173.252 - - [12/Jun/2014:23:19:39 +0200] "POST /wp-content/themes/theme-name/husv.php HTTP/1.0" 200 210 "-" "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)"
```

A post like this is also done to imagestyle.php instead of husv.php. (Like it was trying stuff). And imagestyle.php was found.

I'm wondering how to stop this. Is this a known issue?
Is setting the theme-name folder to 644 enough?

Comment: FTP to your site. Delete the two files. Change your FTP password. Change your WP admin account passwords. Talk to your hosting to see if any other customer on your shared hosting has complained of a similar problem. I've had it but not the same files. The hosting company soon changed their FTP access processes as a number had complained. A last step is to back up your site, upload a fresh WP install and use a clean theme.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What you said has already been done. FTP pw changed, admin login changed and db login. I also downloaded a fresh wordpress install. The theme is handmade, i removed the files, and I found no code injection The site was hacked again on a different server.

Comment: If you're on a shared hosting then you may want to contact your provider and ask if an another account has caused the FTP breach. Not uncommon. You may have to move to your own server (through your hosting) to rule out whether another account has caused the issue, or whether, perhaps, the passwords or WP version you are using are secure enough... use the latest stable release always.

Comment: I'll contact the provider, I know im on a shared hosting. I'm hoping it's not me. I did use the latest WP version. Thanks for the help so far.